# Java ScriptEngine for Javascript: using XML

Tags: java, javascript, xml, rhino, e4x

As I noticed on [oracle.com](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html) that Java has no support for XML literal in E4X implementation.

The question is: Is there any other way to process XML in JavaScript with Java Rhino ScriptEngine?

Comment: Which browsers do you target? I was a big fan of XML+XSL client side, but JSON changed everything. There is an xslt to convert xml in JSON http://code.google.com/p/xml2json-xslt/ but it may provide strange formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rhino that was bundled with Java 1.6 is missing E4X support. From http://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/e4x_is_not_mustang:

> Although Mustang includes Rhino 1.6R1 (and probably will change to
>   Rhino 1.6R2 before FCS), we are not including E4X (ECMAScript for XML)
>   support in it.

You should get Rhino directly from [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Rhino). All version from 1.6R1 onward have support for E4X.